# Trapezoidal method for ODE results in cmsing warning

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages, undocumented

I try to solve an ODE using the [trapezoidal method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule_(differential_equations)). I do the following (Definition of `Trapezoidal` is from this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/69963/1871)):

```
Trapezoidal = {"FixedStep", 
  Method -> {"ImplicitRungeKutta", 
    "Coefficients" -> "ImplicitRungeKuttaLobattoIIIACoefficients", 
    "DifferenceOrder" -> 1, 
    "ImplicitSolver" -> {"FixedPoint", 
      AccuracyGoal -> MachinePrecision, PrecisionGoal -> MachinePrecision, 
      "IterationSafetyFactor" -> 1}}};

y = t /. First@NDSolve[{y'[t]  ==Sin[t]-2y[t], y[0] == 0}, y, {t, 0, 20}, 
  Method -> Trapezoidal, StartingStepSize -> 1/100];
Plot[y[t], {t, 0, 20}]
```

But I get a warning message:

> `` NDSolve`ImplicitRungeKutta::cmsing ``: Singular coefficient matrix encountered for `` NDSolve`ImplicitRungeKuttaLobattoIIIACoefficients ``, which is not suitable for stiff systems.

Then I try to plot these points resulting from the procedure as a path, but still can't get that working.

Any idea how I can make this work?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not to use 'Method ->"ExplicitEuler"`?

Comment: The line `Plot[y[t], {t, 0, 20}]` is obviously wrong. It should be `q[t]`

Comment: Also, why are you trying to use trapezoidal method? Is it for pedagogical purposes?

Comment: If you don't understand what `/.` means and is just using it blindly, please read document of [`ReplaceAll` (`/.`)](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html?q=ReplaceAll) carefully. It's a function that you must understand its usage.

Comment: One should never guess the usage of unknown _Mathematica_ functions. Document of _Mathematica_ is quite informative and suitable for self-learning, please read it carefully. If you want to extract various info from `InterpolatingFunction`, please read these posts: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19043/1871 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/28341/1871 See also the document [_Utility Packages for Numerical Differential Equation Solving_](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolvePackages.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me extend my comments to an answer. First of all,

> Then I try to plot these points resulting from the procedure as a path, but still can't get that working.

As mentioned above, this is because you're using `ReplaceAll` (`/.`) blindly, `/.` just doesn't have the functionality you're imagining. Here I'll simply show the fix without explanation:

```
ysol = y /. First@
    NDSolve[{y'[t] == Sin[t] - 2 y[t], y[0] == 0}, y, {t, 0, 20}, 
     Method -> Trapezoidal, StartingStepSize -> 1/5];

ListPlot[Transpose@{ysol["Coordinates"][[1]], ysol["ValuesOnGrid"]}]
```

[image]

Please read document of [`ReplaceAll` (`/.`)](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html?q=ReplaceAll), [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19043/1871) and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/28341/1871) post and the document [*Utility Packages for Numerical Differential Equation Solving*](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolvePackages.html) to understand why the points are extracted in this manner.

> **Remark**
>
> A less advanced solution is
>
> ```
> ListPlot@Table[{t, ysol[t]}, {t, 0, 20, 1/5}]
> ```
>
> Notice this method doesn't extract the original data so if you compare
> the data with that obtained above, you'll observe extremely small
> discrepency, but this should be trivial for any pedagogical purpose
> programming.

OK, then let's talk about the interesting part of this question:

> I get a warning message `` NDSolve`ImplicitRungeKutta::cmsing ``…

Conclusion first: **this is merely a warning, `NDSolve` still uses the trapezoid rule for ODE solving, so you can simply ignore it**.

Why do I know it can be ignored? Because after some spelunking using the debugger tool (you may start from [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/119307/1871) to learn the usage of debugger), I notice the warning is caused by an internal function `` NDSolve`IRKDump`InvertWeights ``, its definition is

```
Internal`$ContextMarks = False;
?NDSolve`IRKDump`InvertWeights
```

[image]

As we can see, when the method `` NDSolve`ImplicitRungeKuttaLobattoIIIACoefficients `` is set, `` NDSolve`IRKDump`InvertWeights `` always returns `$Failed`. I'm not familiar with implicit Runge-Kutta method so cannot comment on this design. I just want to point out that, if the first definition is cleared, and undocumented option `Method -> "IterativeRefinement"` is not set in `LinearSolve`, `InvertWeights` will be able to find the invert weights:

```
(* You need to use Method -> "ImplicitRungeKutta" at least once
   before executing the following code *)
NDSolve`IRKDump`InvertWeights[
  NDSolve`ImplicitRungeKuttaLobattoIIIACoefficients, __] =.

NDSolve`IRKDump`InvertWeights[method_, {amat_, bvec_, cvec_}, prec_] := 
 Module[{dvec}, Block[{Message}, dvec = LinearSolve[Transpose[amat], bvec];]; 
  If[! NDSolve`IRKDump`NumberVectorQ[dvec], $Failed, dvec]]
(* {0., 1.} *)
```

After executing the code above, you'll find the warning `` NDSolve`ImplicitRungeKutta::cmsing `` no longer shows up. I'm not sure if it's safe to modify code like this, the obtained solution remains the same anyway.

"But wait, how do you know the trapezoid rule is really used internally? Perhaps `NDSolve` has turned to something else! " This can be easily verified by comparing the result to a home-made trapezoid rule solver:

```
t0 = 0; tend = 5; dt = 1/2; y0 = 0;
rhsfunc = {t, y} |-> Sin[t] - 2 y;
sys = {y'[t] == rhsfunc[t, y[t]], y[t0] == y0};
asol = y /. First@DSolve[sys, y, {t}]
nsol = NDSolveValue[sys, y, {t, t0, tend}, 
   Method -> {FixedStep, 
     Method -> {ImplicitRungeKutta, 
       Coefficients -> ImplicitRungeKuttaLobattoIIIACoefficients, 
       DifferenceOrder -> 1}}, StartingStepSize -> dt];

onestep = With[{f = rhsfunc}, 
   Compile[{t, y0, dt}, 
    Last@FixedPoint[
      Function[{ylst}, 
       Module[{k1, k2}, 
        k1 = f[t, ylst[[1]]]; 
        k2 = f[dt + t, ylst[[2]]]; 
        {ylst[[1]], 1/2 dt (k1 + k2) + ylst[[1]]}]], 
        {y0, y0}, SameTest -> (Abs[#1[[2]] - #2[[2]]] < 1*^-10 &)]]];
tlst = Range[t0, tend, dt];
datatrapezoid = FoldList[onestep[#2, #, dt] &, 0, Most@tlst];
datansol = nsol["ValuesOnGrid"];
ListPlot[{datatrapezoid, datansol}, DataRange -> {t0, tend}]~Show~
 Plot[asol[t], {t, t0, tend}]
```

[image]

```
(* Error Check *)
asol@tlst - # & /@ {datansol, datatrapezoid} // 
 ListPlot[#, PlotMarkers -> {"X", "O"}, DataRange -> {t0, tend}] &
```

[image]

As we can see, the numeric error of `NDSolve` solution and home-made solver solution consistents, so it's reasonable to believe the trapezoid rule is indeed used by `NDSolve`.

Comment: Thanks for this!