# How to Copy formatted code without backslashes added?

Tags: front-end, export, output-formatting, interoperability, clipboard

By default code copied from the FrontEnd is formatted with backslashes added at the ends of lines. For example, evaluating in a Notebook

```
Range[40]
```

and copying the output produces the following when pasted in a text editor:

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, \
> 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, \
> 37, 38, 39, 40}
> ```

I would like to turn off addition of the backslashes at the ends of lines for the `Copy` command by default while preserving the wrapping with custom `PageWidth`.

For example with a PageWidth of 35:

```
SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, "ExportTypesetOptions" -> {"PageWidth" -> 35}]
```

copying the output of `Range[40]` and pasting here should yield:

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
> 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 
> 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 
> 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34,
> 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40}
> ```

(Custom `PageWidth` wrapping is applied but without backslashes at the ends of lines.)

Is it possible?

---

#### Update

Inside of the Notebook interface it is possible to achieve the desired formatting as follows:

```
CellPrint@TextCell[ToString[Range[40], InputForm], "Text", 
  TextJustification -> 1, PageWidth -> 330]
```

[image: screenshot]

But I still can't figure out how to copy such output keeping this formatting...

Comment: I was just about to close this as a duplicate of [(17540)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17540/121) when I read again the point about backslashes.  Is that a separate issue from page width?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes, it is a separate issue.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes, but I mean manual copying via the right-click menu (or `Ctrl+C`), not programmatic copying via `CopyToClipboard`.

Comment: Would you accept anything other than a complete automatic (`Ctrl`+`C`) solution?  I mean for example would using a Palette button for the copy be OK?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard If there is no hidden option which controls this behavior, anything like a hotkey or menu item would be sufficient. A Palette solution is not very practical for such task.

Comment: have you tried "Ctrl-Shift-C" ?

Comment: @Wouter `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`C` copies unformatted code without wrapping. I need formatted code but without backslashes.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Why not right click and select convert to "Raw Input Form" and then use regular copy? And if that is too complicated you can make a custom hotkey for that.

Comment: @M.R. This operation will delete comments from the code and change its appearance: for example, `a // f` will be converted to `f[a]`. I need to preserve the appearance with custom `PageWidth`.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this could work for you:

```
copyOutput[expr_, pageWidth_:20] := Module[{f = $TemporaryPrefix, s},
   s = OpenWrite[f, PageWidth -> pageWidth];
   Write[s, expr]; CopyToClipboard[Import[f]];
   Close[f]; Return @ expr
]
```

So when you run this:

```
In[]:= copyOutput[Range[40]]        
Out[]= {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, \
        22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40}
```

the output you want is copied to the clipboard:

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 
7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 
12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 
17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 
22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 
27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 
32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 
37, 38, 39, 40}
```