# Formatting output for use in forums etc

Tags: front-end, output-formatting, customization, output, clipboard

If we take the (simple) example

```
x = 1;
y = 2;
z = 3;

x + y + z
```

we get the (complete screen) result when copying into a more basic interface, such as a web forum or text editor

```
In[1]:= x = 1;
y = 2;
z = 3;

In[4]:= x + y + z

Out[4]= 6
```

Is there any clever way to modify this output (preferably during the copy/paste operation) to become

```
x = 1;
y = 2;
z = 3;

x + y + z

> 6
```

(or some other 'minimalistic' output indicator than '>'), removing the input labels as well as reducing the output labels. It would be very convenient to have when pasting Mathematica code/output in web forums as well as in the verbatim environment in LaTeX. TIA.

Comment: Related: "[Programmatically convert notebook input cells to text file](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/146167/280)."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable copying of the cell labels on the global level:

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, {
  "ExportTypesetOptions" -> {"PageWidth" -> 90, "IncludeCellLabels" -> False}, 
  "ExportMultipleCellsOptions" -> {"IncludeCellLabels" -> False}}]
```

(I also set copied page width to be [suitable for StackExchange](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17540/how-to-copy-code-out-of-notebook-to-an-external-text-editor-without-extra-line-f/17603#comment52064_17603)).

This setting will persists between FrontEnd sessions.

---

As regards to prepending `>`  to the output expression (I would recommend prepending `>`      to have it formatted as *code* of the output), it can be achieved by low-level Notebook programming. Here is a start:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], CellEpilog :> Module[{out = NextCell[], boxes, newboxes},
    If[CurrentValue[out, GeneratedCell],
     boxes = NotebookRead@out;
     newboxes = boxes /. {BoxData[s_String] :> BoxData[">     " <> s]};
     NotebookWrite[out, newboxes];
     ]]];
```

Now any simple output will be prepended by `>`     .