# Mapping between lists and Mapping Formats

Tags: list-manipulation, format, arguments

I've been writing a conversion 'script' between two robot description formats and thought I would try out Mathematica as I thought it sounded pretty awesome. *Although by this point I should have done it manually!*

I'm sure there's a much better way to do the entire mapping process. I had trouble trying to apply the mappings from the elements between the joints and the links.
I had tried using variations on `Rule @@ ConnectionsOrder`, with various operators `/., //, @@, @@@ /@`

1. Is there a more idiomatic implementation of the below?

Since Mathematica is symbolically based, I thought something may exists where you can define a format, and then specifying another and some rules to convert and having everything work nicely.
Does such a thing exist? - I have been text wrangling to basically manually convert the files.

```
jointsOrder = {"HAA", "HFE", "KFE", "WHEEL"};
linksOrder = {"BASE", "HIP", "THIGH", "shank_fixed", "WHEEL_L"};
connectionsOrder = Riffle[linksOrder, jointsOrder];
connections = 
 BlockMap[Apply[Rule], Flatten[Subsequences[connectionsOrder, {2}]], 
  2]
```

Comment: `Thread[LinksOrder[[1 ;; Length[JointsOrder]]] -> JointsOrder]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`BlockMap`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BlockMap.html) can do more of the work than you are allowing it to:

```
BlockMap[Apply[Rule], connectionsOrder, 2, 1]
```

> ```
> {"BASE" -> "HAA", "HAA" -> "HIP", "HIP" -> "HFE", "HFE" -> "THIGH", 
>  "THIGH" -> "KFE", "KFE" -> "shank_fixed", "shank_fixed" -> "WHEEL", 
>  "WHEEL" -> "WHEEL_L"}
> ```

Comment: For the second part of my question do you know of / point me to a tutorial/manpage of a general method for converting between structured formats?

Comment: @ixil There is [**Manipulating Lists**](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ManipulatingListsOverview.html) and [**Expressions**](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ExpressionsOverview.html).  Browsing top questions in [tag:list-manipulation] and [tag:expression-manipulation] would be useful too.

Answer (score 6):

```
Partition[connectionsOrder, 2, 1, {1, -1}, {}, Rule]
```

> ```
> {"BASE" -> "HAA", "HAA" -> "HIP", "HIP" -> "HFE", "HFE" -> "THIGH",  
>  "THIGH" -> "KFE", "KFE" -> "shank_fixed", "shank_fixed" -> "WHEEL",    
> "WHEEL" -> "WHEEL_L"}
> ```

or

```
Rule @@@ Partition[connectionsOrder, 2, 1]
```

> ```
> {"BASE" -> "HAA", "HAA" -> "HIP", "HIP" -> "HFE", "HFE" -> "THIGH",  
>  "THIGH" -> "KFE", "KFE" -> "shank_fixed", "shank_fixed" -> "WHEEL",    
> "WHEEL" -> "WHEEL_L"}
> ```

Also

```
EdgeRules @ PathGraph @ connectionsOrder
```

> ```
> {"BASE" -> "HAA", "HAA" -> "HIP", "HIP" -> "HFE", "HFE" -> "THIGH",   
>  "THIGH" -> "KFE", "KFE" -> "shank_fixed", "shank_fixed" -> "WHEEL",   
>  "WHEEL" -> "WHEEL_L"}
> ```

Comment: I notice you are omitting the quote markdown in the output formatting.  Now that the block style is not the "ugly yellow" I think you should consider using it, as the syntax highlighting is useful IMHO.

Comment: Thank you @Mr.Wizard; very good suggestion.

Comment: I see you figured out I meant "code markdown" -- it's the quote block that is no longer yellow.  Anyway the form you have now seems like a good one and an alternative to the one I use.  Do you prefer its appearance?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, yours look better. Is there a way to do the line wrapping (I had to break the code into lines manually)?

Comment: Do you mean basic line wrapping, or breaks at specific points?  [This](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/17603/121) usually handles the former, but I do tend to manually edit breaks when it looks better.

Comment: I meant to get from code in block quote (at the end of  my post) to the form just above it .

Comment: I just paste, select the output, then click the **{ }** and **"** editor buttons in that order.  If that's not what you mean, sorry, I must be too tired to understand tonight.  Try tomorrow. :-)

Comment: thank you... that's what i meant.

Comment: I accepted @Mr.Wizard's as it's the most succint. But thanks for pointing out these other functions. I feel there are so many ways to 'skin a cat' in mathematica - that's half the problem!

Comment: @ixil, that would be my choice too :)